# How to use AWS S3 PersistableDownload on Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, persistence

Has anyone been able to use PersistableDownload on AWS Android SDK? I've been trying to use it to resume downloads when the App crashes, but with no success so far. I don't think I'm getting the concept serialize/deserialize right. Here is the code I got so far:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = getAmazonS3Client(Regions.SA_EAST_1);
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(s3Client);

String bucket = "MyBucket";
String key = "IMG_20140915_132548.jpg";
String[] parts = key.split("/");
String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

final String full_path = "/storage/sdcard0/" + fileName;
File file = new File(full_path);
FileInputStream fis = null;
if(file.exists()) {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        PersistableDownload persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis); 
        Download meuDown = tx.resumeDownload(persistableUpload);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, "IMG_20140915_132548.jpg");
    Download download = tx.download(getRequest, file, new S3ProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent arg0) {
            long transferred = arg0.getBytesTransferred();
            Log.d("AWS3", "" + transferred);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPersistableTransfer(PersistableTransfer arg0) {
            Log.d("AWS3", "Writing to file");
            File f = new File("/storage/sdcard0/resume-upload");
                FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                if (f.exists() == false) 
                    f.createNewFile();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                arg0.serialize(fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I noticed that the onPersistableTransfer method is only called once, so I don't know how all the received bytes are serialized to the disk.

Any advices on how to get PersistableDownload to work? I'm using the SDK 2.1, with a real cell phone (Android 4.4.4) and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above code, I see that you are passing the partially downloaded image file to resume the download process.

```
if(file.exists()) {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        PersistableDownload persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis); 
        Download meuDown = tx.resumeDownload(persistableUpload);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here file is referring to the partially downloaded image file. You will need to pass the file "/storage/sdcard0/resume-upload" to resume the upload.